# Trigger Iron Router Route from Angular Controller - Meteor

Tags: angularjs, redirect, meteor, iron-router, angular-controller

I have a dynamic table with one edit button per row created with Meteor.js. When clicked, I need to route to another page.

I´ve tried using `$location.url(/mypage)`

but it produces the angular like hashtag url like

> mysite.com/currentpage/#mypage

What I need is go to the page with iron router.

I´ve tried

```
  $scope.edit = function (content) {
            Router.render('MyPage');
        };
```

But it does not work.

**What is the correct way to route to a page with Iron Router from within an Angular Controller?**

Answer (score 0):

`.render()` is a function you use in the router itself. To navigate to a route use `.go()`:

```
Router.go('MyPage');
```